# Colorscheme Errors (E185) with vimrc and sessions

Tags: vimrc, colorscheme, sessions

I have a couple of things which suggest there's an issue with the way I use `colorscheme` with my `vimrc` file.

- Errors when running `source ~/.vimrc`
- The colorscheme used when opening a vim session

---

**Sourcing vimrc**

If I update my `vimrc` file and `source` it to see the changes in my current session I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim80/syntax/synload.vim:
line   19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'vim-monokai-tasty'
```

Despite the complaint the colour scheme does seem to update to be `monokai-tasty`.
The colour scheme is at `~/.vim/colors/monokai-tasty.vim`.

---

**Vim Sessions**

If I start a vim session with `vim -S /path/to/session.vim` some colour scheme, other than `monokai-tasty` is used.
This would be a time where I may use `:source ~/.vimrc` and get the above errors, but also the correct colour scheme.

Saving the vim session after making changes to the colour scheme seems to have no effect upon starting a new session.

---

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Here is where you can find my [vim](https://github.com/BrokenFlows/dotfiles/tree/96e197530eb2f078f7e4c89f1b563be4bdae1ca7/vim) and [vim/colors](https://github.com/BrokenFlows/dotfiles/tree/96e197530eb2f078f7e4c89f1b563be4bdae1ca7/vim/colors) directories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The colorscheme in question, "monokai-tasty.vim" does not properly set `g:colors_name`:

```
let g:colors_name = "vim-monokai-tasty"
```

`g:colors_name` should be set to the file name of the colorscheme without the `.vim`.  Correct:

```
let g:colors_name = "monokai-tasty"
```

When the two differ, setting colorscheme initially appears to work.  However there are instances where vim reloads the colorscheme, and it uses `g:colors_name` to do that.  At that point the error will be generated.

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much.

Comment: It would be worth it to create a issue in there Github issue tracker if they have one.